Android Compose with Navigation - DeepLink with full URI
I’m using Jetpack Navigation with Compose in my application, and I need to parse a URI that can originate from two different sources:
1.  A QR code scanned internally within the app.
2.  A deep link.
For the QR code use case, the implementation is straightforward—I scan the code and pass the value to the appropriate Composable for further processing, using a simple data object as the route.
However, I’m facing challenges with the deep link. My requirement is to retrieve the entire URI, but I can’t use my standard route because the compiler raises an error about the parameter not being present.
The workaround I’ve implemented is to have a dedicated Composable navigation entry point for handling deep links. From there, I extract the full URI from the intent and redirect it to my standard route.
I’m wondering if I might have missed something or if this is simply a limitation of the SDK. Does anyone have a better solution or recommendation for handling this scenario?
This is my current implementation:
@Serializable data class URIRoute(val uri: String)

fun NavController.navigateToURI(
    uri: String,
    navOptions: NavOptions? = null
) = navigate(URIRoute(uri), navOptions)

fun NavGraphBuilder.uriScreen() {
    composable<URIRoute> {
        URIScreen()
    }
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.uriScreenDeepLink(
    navigateToUri: (String) -> Unit
) {
    composable(
        route = "uriDeepLink",
        deepLinks = listOf(
            navDeepLink {
                uriPattern = BuildConfig.MY_URI
            }
        )
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        val deepLinkIntent = backStackEntry.arguments?.getParcelable(
            NavController.KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT,
            Intent::class.java
        )
        navigateToUri(deepLinkIntent?.data.toString())
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = HomeRoute,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        ...
        issuerScreenDeepLink(navController::navigateToURI)
        issuerScreen()
        ...
    }
}

